# Host port with DB to Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, port

I have host with PostgreSQL and Docker container. PostgreSQL work on 5432 port. Docker container must connect to database. How to connect container with database through Dockerfile or run command? `EXPOSE 5432` and `docker run -p 5432:5432 ...` did not help.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-entries-to-container-hosts-file-add-host) page:

> Sometimes you need to connect to the Docker host from within your
>   container. To enable this, pass the Docker host’s IP address to the
>   container using the `--add-host` flag. To find the host’s address, use
>   the `ip addr show` command.

```
$ HOSTIP=`ip -4 addr show scope global dev eth0 | grep inet | awk '{print \$2}' | cut -d / -f 1`
$ docker run  --add-host=docker:${HOSTIP} --rm -it busybox telnet docker 5432
```

`EXPOSE` or `-p` flag work the other way around e.g. publish container ports to host which you don't want here.

Comment: Or just connect to the IP of the PostgreSQL host.