# How to make postgres.app db accessible to docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgres.app

I got postgres.app running locally on my Mac and would like my local docker container to be able to connect to it. How do I best do this?

I found this post that suggests to pass the Docker host’s IP address to a container using the --add-host flag ([Host port with DB to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327522/host-port-with-db-to-docker-container)). However, my laptop's IP address changes frequently. Isn't there an easier way of doing this? Isn't there an easy way to open a local port to a container?

Comment: You can also use the network address of the host in the subnetwork of docker containers, which is `172.17.0.1` by default. It works nicely on a Linux host, but I am not sure that would work on a Mac.

Comment: @bekce That sounds like I'd like to give that a try. Any pointers as to how to use the network address of my host in the subnetwork of my docker container?

Comment: Well, just try `docker run -it --rm ubuntu`, once inside: `apt update && apt install telnet && telnet 172.17.0.1 5432` and see whether it can connect or not.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out how to do this and ... the connection was refused.

Answer (score 4):

Few things

- Use `docker.for.mac.localhost` as your HOST (This assumes you have the latest Docker for Mac as @Pete mentioned)
- Make sure there is such a record in `~/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6/pg_hba.conf`

`host   all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust`

- Change this line `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` in `~/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6/postgresql.conf`

to

`listen_addresses = '*'`

or

`listen_addresses = 'localhost, docker.for.mac.localhost'`

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about a developers workstations, you could start your Docker Container inside the Host Network.

```
docker run --net=host myContainer
```

So your container runs in the same stack as your Host, and should be able to access your postgres.app.

Answer (score 0):

From your container, try connecting to hostname `docker.for.mac.localhost`. For example:

```
psql -U my_user docker.for.mac.localhost -U my_user my_database
```

[From the docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds):

> The Mac has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network
>   access). From 17.06 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the
>   special Mac-only DNS name `docker.for.mac.localhost` which will resolve
>   to the internal IP address used by the host.

Note: this requires Docker for Mac `>= 17.06.0-ce-mac18, 2017-06-28`